# Perimeter of a rounded 'house' (rectangle+regular trapezoid)shape?

Tags: geometry

Imagine a trapezoid stacked on a rectangle, with all six of the corners rounded off. I'm trying to find it's perimeter.

Here is an *unrounded* trapezoid (note, this is obviously not my diagram, so the letters do not match the rectangle below)

[image: diagram of a regular trapezoid with the base labeled 'B', top labeled 'A', the sloped edged labeled 'C' and the height 'H']

Here is a rectangle with the corners rounded off.

[image: rectangle with edges rounded off the longest side is labelled 'A' the shortest 'B'.]

The stack is such that **the A of the rounded rectangle is smoothly attached to the B of the trapezoid** (that is, with *no overhang*), like so:

[image: the two previous images stacked with relabelled sides]

**Note! Please read the diagram carefully! I have relabelled the sides!**

The red lines show the curved top corners, and the angles for the side points.

[image: zoomed in picture of one of the side corners]

This is a 'zoomed in' image of the joint.

I can calculate the perimeter of the rounded rectangle using the [formula on this page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RoundedRectangle.html):

$$p = 2(a + b + pi*r)$$

And the formula for the regular/isosceles trapezoid (without rounded corners) is given [on this page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsoscelesTrapezoid.html):

$$p = a + b + 2\times\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)^2 + h^2}\right)$$

However I need to round the top two obtusely angled corners, and the side obtusely angled corners and factor that in.

The angles would be $\theta_{top} = \tan{\frac{a-b}{h}}+90$ and $\theta_{side} = \tan{\frac{h}{a-b}}+90$ in degrees, so the contributions should be $\theta\times{\pi}r$.

But plugging this into Wolfram Alpha gives me a computation time-out error, making me think it's wrong.

Knowing A, B, D, R and H what is the *correct* formula for the perimeter?

Comment: Representing $c$ in terms of $a,b,h$, what is the perimeter of the trapezoid? What is the perimeter of the rounded rectangle? What is the common side length that should be subtracted after attaching both shapes?

Comment: @peterwhy that's what I was hoping to find out. This isn't homework, so I'm looking for answers not hints.

Comment: Am I right that the distance $a$ in the rounded rectangle is only the length of its top, not including the two extra quarter-circles? And that the trapezoid's side of length $a$ is attached to that top of the rounded rectangle, not including the quarter circles? It also seems like you need different letters than in your diagram for the trapezoid, to make the longer trapezoid side possible to connect to the side A of the rounded rectangle.

Comment: @coffeemath *Am I right that the distance a in the rounded rectangle is only the length of its top, not including the two extra quarter-circles?* Yes, the diagram and linked page hopefully makes that clear. *And that the trapezoid's side of length a is attached to that top of the rounded rectangle, not including the quarter circles?* Not clear what you mean, they're attached so there's no gap. In terms of relabelling: as per the question - "The stack is such that the A of the rounded rectangle is smoothly attached to the B of the trapezoid.". I'll see if I can make it clearer

Comment: In the present picture side a of the rectangle is attached to the longer side a of the trapezoid, not to the shorter side b of the trapezoid.

Comment: @coffeemath yes correct, is that an issue?

Comment: As the lower base of the trapezium is longer than the horizontal side of the rectangle (because apparently $b>a$), I expect overhangs under the "roof" and two cusps where the two quadrilaterals meet. The total perimeter is

$$\text{Perimeter of the trapezium} + \text{Perimeter of the rectangle} - 2a$$

Comment: @peterwhy please see some of the recent edits today, and this part of the question: *"The stack is such that the A of the rounded rectangle is smoothly attached to the B of the trapezoid"* and *"However I need to round the top two obtusely angled corners, and the side obtusely angled corners and factor that in."*

Comment: @peterwhy I have made another edit to make the question foolproof (or at least I hope so!)

Comment: @coffeemath does the current question text make sense to you?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage If you round the trapezium consistently like how you rounded the rectangle, by expanding the (unrounded) perimeter outward by $r$, then the calculation would be easier.

Comment: I still can't tell from the diagram exactly how the rounded part of the circles are used in the connection. Maybe a blown-up picture of one of the corners where the circles are... also is the angle determining what part of the circles is used known, or does it need to be left as part of the data of the figure?

Comment: @peterwhy I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @coffeemath I think you can work it out from the information?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I mean, why did you define rounded corners of the rectangle outside the $a\times b$ rectangle, but define rounded corners of the trapezium sometimes inside (the upper base angles) and sometimes outside (the lower base angles)? The calculation would be easier if you first combine a trapezium and a rectangle, and then expand its perimeter outward by $r$.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage No I can't "work it out from the information". The diagram is unclear where it is hand-drawn by what looks like marker pens, the angles of the circles are not given (in degrees or radians) but look like 45 degrees ...

Comment: @peterwhy I didn't realise I had. I'm not sure what I should do differently about that.

Comment: @coffeemath I try to work out the angles in the question text. I'm guessing you read that and have concluded I've done it wrong? Let me know if you can see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually fairly simple, if you know some measurements. In total, you have a sharp cornered item, that lies in the center of a rounded item:

[image: rounded house shape redrawn with all angles and sides labelled. The side angles are beta, and the top 'roof' angles are alpha, the angles on the base are labelled gamma. The inner height h is shown as is h prime, the outer height]

As is easily visible, the outer circumference is the inner circumference, but also larger by the sum of the circle segments. These circle segments sum up (from symmetry) $\alpha+\alpha+\beta+\beta+\gamma+\gamma=2\times (\alpha+\beta+\gamma)=360°$. Due to the definition you had of $\gamma=90°$ we also know that $\alpha+\beta=90°$, and from symmetry, we also know $\beta+\theta=90°$. We also can turn h' into h by substracting r (which is trivial), which we only need for area or calculating c. Which is triangonometric: $$c=\sqrt{(h'-r)^2+\left(\frac {a-d}{2}\right)^2}$$

As the result the circumference $C$ is just larger by one circle with the radius r: $$C=a+2b + 2c + d + 2 \pi r$$

Likewise the area is the inner area plus the full circle area, plus the areas of thickness r that are between the inner and outer perimeter. This boils down to $$A= a \times b +\frac 1 2 (a+d)\times h + d \times r + a \times r + 2 b \times r + 2c \times r $$

### not-sharing a line?

The circumference does decidedly not change at all, if the connection is made with a *gap* of height g to the rounded body, so that the rounded corner has a tangential connection to the trapezoid The only thing that actually changes is the nomenclature of $h_2$ and $h_2'$: in contrast to the $h_1$ and $h_1'$ the following must be true: $$h_2'+g=h_1'=h_2+r+g=h_1+r$$

[image]

How big is $g$ then? Simple sinus solves that: $g=r\sin(beta)$, where we already know that $\beta = 90°-\theta$.

Following through with the calculations from the start, the **circumference** is unchanged, only when the *Area* is calculated, the change does matter, because it relies on the value of $h_1$ and we only have $h_2$ or $h_2'$, which we can convert into the needed value via $g$.

Comment: Based on OP's diagram, OP's $h$ should be your $h'_2$ in your second diagram. $c$ is not a given length, but may be calculated from a right-angled triangle with vertical side $h'_2 -r+g$ and horizontal side $\frac{a-d}2$. But what is $g$?$$\begin{align*}
g&=r\sin\beta = r\cos\theta\\
\tan\theta &= \frac{h'_2-r+g}{(a-d)/2}
\end{align*}$$ Which might take some time to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned in comments above that the following construction of the rounded polygon would make the calculation easier: by first combining a trapezium and a rectangle, and then expand its perimeter outward by $r$.

I added some green lines to the diagram below, showing expanded perimeter outside a convex "house" hexagon:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4DsT.png]

The perimeter of the rounded hexagon is simply the perimeter of the unrounded hexagon plus one circumference with radius $r$:

$$a + 2b + 2c' + d' + 2\pi r$$

What's difficult is to find the adjusted upper base $d'$, the adjusted height of the trapezium $h'$, and the adjusted legs $c'$.

Zooming into "the joint":

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9UjM.jpg]

Consider the length of the solid line between the trapezium and the rounded rectangle,

$$a + 2r\sin \theta = d + 2\frac{h}{\tan\theta}$$

Solve for $\theta$ (which I am not able to do by hand for now), then

$$\begin{align*}
c &= \frac{h}{\sin\theta}\\
c' &= c - h\tan\frac\theta2\\
d' &= d - 2h\tan\frac\theta2\\
\end{align*}$$

The $\theta/2$ comes from considering the rounded angles that cut into the upper base corners of the trapezium.

Comment: do note that c' and c are interchangeable, just like d' and d - as I pointed out.

Comment: @Trish They are not interchangeable, as $c$ and $d$ are based on the original trapezium, and in OP's question, the rounded corners of the upper base angles (the red arcs) cut into the original trapezium.

Comment: I account that for bad drawing skills of OP

Comment: @peterwhy they are actually, if you follow the logic and reasoning in the linked Wolfram posts. Apologies for not explaining that well in my question!

Comment: @AncientSwordRage The Wolfram posts describe what a (n unrounded) trapezoid and a rounded rectangle are, but it was up to your question to explain how you would round the trapezoid and how you would join the two shapes together.

Comment: @peterwhy it was ignorance on my part that I didn't realise my explanation was ambiguous. Trish seems to have understood my meaning however.